# Access multiple included layouts from a different xml file

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, inflate

I'm trying to access a `TextView` from an included layout but I don't know how.
This is the layout I `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` on my `onCreate`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can see that this layout includes another layout, app_bar_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.branco.sauce.home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home"
        android:id="@+id/includeContentHome"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now this other layout includes my final xml file, the one I have a `TextView`, content_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.branco.sauce.home"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home"

    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ROLA 3"
        android:textSize="100px"
        android:id="@+id/txtRola3"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is to access the TextView which id is `txtRola3` in the following method:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            final LayoutInflater inflateContentHome = getLayoutInflater();
            final View viewContentHome = inflateContentHome.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_home, null);
            TextView txtTest = (TextView)viewContentHome.findViewById(R.id.includeContentHome).findViewById(R.id.txtRola3);
            txtTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("You clicked on the textview");
                }
            });
}
```

As you can see, I've tried inflating some layouts but I have no idea how to make this work. I mean, I can see the TextView and it's text, but the `listener` is not working. I'm accually doing this so I can learn and access my `ListView`(which right now I can't populate with data). I know this kind of question has been answered before, but since I have three layouts and one includes the other, I couldn't get any luck with others answers.

EDIT: home.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    }
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            final LayoutInflater inflateContentHome = getLayoutInflater();
            final View viewContentHome = inflateContentHome.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_home, null);
            TextView txtTest = (TextView)viewContentHome.findViewById(R.id.includeContentHome).findViewById(R.id.txtRola3);
            txtTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("You clicked on the textview");
                }
            });
}
}
```

OBS: My code has roughly 800 lines, so I added here what matters the most.

Comment: you can use <include> to add different xml

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, @KrishnaJ

Comment: <include layout="@layout/app_bar_home"/> you did not  specify layout file in <include>

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges May be you need to find your views in your `onCreate` or `onCreateView` and then you can use it anywhere in your code.

Comment: @KrishnaJ, I have already included the layout. What I want is to access the Itens in the.

Comment: @jaydroider, I agree with you. The problem is, how can I find my views?

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges Could you show me full code.

Comment: @jaydroider I edited the question and added some of the code, what really matters. The rest are some useless methods for this matter.

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges You just try with this `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);` replace with this `final LayoutInflater inflateContentHome = getLayoutInflater();`. i think your activity not be able to identify inflater.

Comment: I get this exception `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.` here: `final View viewContentHome = inflateContentHome.inflate(R.layout.app_bar_home, null);` And this is how I did: `Context context = getApplicationContext();` `onCreate` and `final LayoutInflater inflateContentHome = LayoutInflater.from(context);`

Comment: @BrunoBrandãoBorges Have you taken `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity` ? please show that code.

Comment: @jaydroider `ActionBarActivity`. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I don't need to create an inflater, assuming all three layouts are 'connected'. All I did was `findViewByID` as if my `textview` was on the main layout.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                TextView k = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rola3);
                k.setOnClickListeer...
}
```